# Create specific version of COM-object

Tags: c#, com, activex

I have multiple versions of a COM-object with the ProgId "MyActiveX.Environment" on my system. These versions are registered at the same time.

I now want to create a specific version of that COM-object and don't know how to do that.

The following line will give me an instance:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyActiveX.Environment", true);
```

I excpected that the following line gives me the version 2.0 but it fails:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyActiveX.Environment.2.0.0.0", true);
```

I see there is a Version 2.0.0.0 registered in the registry under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID...\InprocServer32\2.0.0.0.

Comment: With one progid, you'll have access to one version. So, your COM object should add a "MyActiveX.Environment.2.0.0.0" registry key under CLSID and point InprocServer32 to a specific versioned dll

Comment: @mjwills Exception says "Invalid ProgId." (COMException)

Comment: @SimonMourier I have access to the source code of the com-object assembly. Is there a way to tell regasm it should create an appropriate registry key if the assembly is registrated? Regasm is the way we use to register the com-object.

Comment: Just change (or Add if there wasn't any) the ProgId attribute of your new version class : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute.aspx before you register it.